# Is there a way to add formset in django-admin without using inline?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-inline-models

I have a model called Employee which is defined as follows:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField("Address", max_length=255)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Is there a way to add multiple name and address of employee for the same department, team and position in django-admin form? I want something like formset including fields name and address for the model Employee where you can enter the department, team and postion and just add the formsets multiple times like how you would do for inlines.

I have not tried anything as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in Django admin by using inline formsets. In your case, you want to allow multiple name and address entries for the same department, team, and position in the Django admin form.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Employee, Department, Team, Position

class EmployeeInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['name', 'address']

EmployeeInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Department,  # Parent model (change to Team or Position as needed)
    Employee,
    form=EmployeeInlineForm,
    extra=1,  # Number of empty forms to display
    can_delete=True,
)

class EmployeeInline(admin.TabularInline):  # Use 'StackedInline' for a different layout
    model = Employee
    formset = EmployeeInlineFormSet
    extra = 1  # Number of empty forms to display

class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EmployeeInline]

admin.site.register(Department, DepartmentAdmin)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be example when we are trying to add Department(or Team or Position) along with adding the employees under that department in the same form. However, for my case I already have the departments in my model. Instead of adding the department, team and position each time I have to add an employee, I want to be able to add multiple employees for the same values of department(or team or position).

Answer (score 1):

**or you can try this way:**

```
from django.forms import formset_factory

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'department', 'team', 'position')

# Create a formset for the EmployeeForm
formset_class = formset_factory(EmployeeForm, extra=0)

# Use the formset in your Django-admin
# Assuming you have a template named 'admin/employee_formset.html'
template_name = 'admin/employee_formset.html'
```

In your admin.py file, jus t render the formset with the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import formset_class

@admin.register(Employee)
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = formset_class

    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

now just in the  admin/employee_formset.html template, render the formset using the following code:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This will create a formset with inline forms for the Employee model, allowing you to enter multiple names and addresses for the same department, team, and position in Django-admin.

Comment: You cannot set formset_class as form in EmployeeAdmin as the form must inherit from 'BaseModelForm'.